# /services/data/v46.0/scheduling giving error: Service not found at: /services/data/v46.0/scheduling

Tags: lightning, rest-api, rest, workbench, field-service-lightning

When I try to call the URI: `/services/data/v46.0/scheduling` from workbench, I am getting the below error:

```
[ {
  "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
  "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
} ]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is field service lightning enabled in the org that workbench is authorized to?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: do you have the [Lightning Scheduler add-on](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/lightning-scheduler/) enabled in the org

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the [Lightning scheduler](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ls_set_up.htm&type=5) is configured in your org. If Scheduler is configured, you will no longer see 'Service not found at: /services/data/v46.0/scheduling/' and the URI `/services/data/v46.0/scheduling/`should return valid resource values as below:

```
{
"getAppointmentCandidates" : "/services/data/v46.0/scheduling/getAppointmentCandidates",
"getAppointmentSlots" : "/services/data/v46.0/scheduling/getAppointmentSlots"
}
```

Note: Lightning Schedule license is different from FSL licenses. So, FSL licenses are not enough to access the lightning scheduler. In order for you to see the Lightning Scheduler App, you need to have the Lightning Scheduler User Access permission set license and permission set.