# Lightning Scheduler in Trailhead playground

Tags: trailhead, lightning-scheduler

Am going thru the Lightning Scheduler trailhead but my trailhead sandbox does not have Lighting Scheduler within the App Builder. How do I upgrade my trailhead sandbox with Scheduler?

Comment: The Lightning Scheduler is available for setup only in Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions per [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.ls_set_up.htm&type=5) . As trailhead orgs are all Dev orgs, I don't think its possible. Also see [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330098/services-data-v46-0-scheduling-giving-error-service-not-found-at-services-da/330117#330117)

Comment: Thanks @Swetha . Trailhead seems to assume you have access to a Lightning Scheduler environ. Perhaps a FSC devorg would allow?

Answer (score 2):

You can sign up for 30 days trial here: https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/lightning-scheduler-trial/?d=cta-body-promo-216